# How do I add detail to input file name in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have two files (html and php). The user uploads a file in the html form and  the php file contains a script to upload the file onto a server. 
It works perfectly, my problem is when User 1 uploads 'wordThing.docx' and User 2 comes along and uploads 'wordThing.docx', User 1's file will be overridden.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br />

<label for="yourName">Your name:</label>
<input type="textbox" name="yourName" id="yourName" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
 <?php
 $userName=$_POST['yourName'];
 $target_path = "uploads/";
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
 {
     echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
     " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else
 {
     echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 }
 ?>
```

I would like to attach the text the user would enter into 'yourName'. Thus the server has contains different file names and none has to be overridden.
So assuming that the users have different names, I would like to know how do I save the file on the server with a name attached to it. For example: User 1's file upload would be 'wordThingSusan.docx'

I hope this isn't too much info. I just wanted to be clear and precise.
Just in case someone is trying to use this code, you need to have a folder named 'uploads' under your directory for it to work.

Comment: Your code assumes the uploads always succeed. **NOT** a good idea. always check `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']` for non-zero codes, which indicate failure.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

to

```
$target_path = $target_path . time() . rand(11, 99) . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

The generated name will be something like uploads/123456789052wordThing.docx

time() will give you the time in format 1234567890, rand(11,99) will generate random number between 11 and 99, so even if 2 people upload same file at same time, the file won't be overwritted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Deepsy. I wish I had thought of that. Makes a whole lot of sense...

Comment: Deepsy, is there a reason I can't upload PDF files with my script? I tried every other file, images, doc, etc... But my PDF file won't upload.

Comment: @EliSkywalker I don't see any format limitation in the following code, it should work fine for every format. Are you getting any error? Are you sure file isn't broken somehow? You can try to print $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] to see if it's returning any error code. Also is move_uploaded_file() failing?

Comment: I have tried many other scripts with and without limitations. They were all successful with other file formats as I looked under 'uploads' folder to verify the file has been uploaded. Except with PDF files. I have numerous PDF files that open perfectly with Adobe Reader, however wont upload with my scripts.

Comment: `echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];` - This code returns "Error: 2"

Comment: UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE
Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Comment: Seems the file you're trying to upload is too big. Maybe you should allow bigger files in your php.ini

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Deepsy. I had just been working so much with the PHP file I forgot about the HTML file. I had `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">` in my HTML. All this time I have been struggling with the PHP script. Pfft, there goes my 5 hours.

Comment: @EliSkywalker you're welcome. By the way, better place MAX_FILE_SIZE in the PHP file, because now it can be easily manupulated. Example: Someone can CTRL + S your page, edit it, put MAX_FILE_SIZE to 999999999 and upload super large file to your server :)

Comment: Sure. I have one in PHP: `if(512000 < $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']){die('Your file is too large. Please upload a smaller file');}` So the maximum file size is 500KB. I used the same size in both PHP and HTML... However it's better only having it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a unix timestamp to the beginning of the filename:

```
<?php
    $userName=$_POST['yourName'];
    $target_path = "uploads/";
    $target_path = $target_path . date('U') . '_' . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
    {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the file_exists method:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

If the check came back that the file already exists I would rename the file and then save it with the new name.

That is how I would attempt it.

Comment: Aah, yes... Check if file exists, if condition is true save in different name, else just save. Nice.